# Flask/Dash application running as a service in windows must be restarted every day to include the current day's date. How to solve the problem?

Tags: python, flask, windows-services, plotly-dash

I have this Flask/Dash application that I deployed as a service running in the background and it works fine. I use a datepicker (calendar) in the application to choose the date for which the data will be fetched and processed. However, the date of today is being grayed (deactivated) every day until I restart the service. I am using this :

```
from dash import dcc
dcc.DatePickerSingle(id='previ_date',
min_date_allowed=datetime.date(2022, 5, 10),
max_date_allowed=datetime.date.today(),
initial_visible_month=datetime.date.today(),
date=datetime.date.today())
```

Normally, the max_date_allowed argument is set to today's date, however, it doesn't behave as expected. Any help on how to overcome this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Setting the max date allowed should probably be done inside a callback. Then, the callback just needs to run rather than restarting the service. You should trigger it with an `interval` that runs infrequently, or something else.

Comment: Great idea. Can the callback triggering be done implicitly without setting some interval manually .. Triggering on click for example?

Comment: Sure, you could have an "update" button, or trigger it on page reload, or any number of things.

Comment: Perfect, now the date setting is inside a callback function and it updates on page reload. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I solved the issue as recommended by @coralvanda by setting the initial value as None, then doing the checking and updating inside a callback function.

```
dcc.DatePickerSingle(id='previ_date',
    min_date_allowed=datetime.date(2022, 5, 10),
    max_date_allowed=None,
    initial_visible_month=None,
    date=datetime.date.today())


@app.callback([Output("previ_date", "max_date_allowed"), Output("previ_date", "initial_visible_month")],
                [Input("previ_date", "max_date_allowed"), Input("previ_date", "initial_visible_month")])

def update_date(max_date, current_month):
    if max_date==None:
        max_date=datetime.date.today()
    if current_month==None:
        current_month=datetime.date.today()
    return max_date, current_month
```